# C# Disable checkboxes when number requirement from radio button is met

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, radio-button

I'm having problems figuring out an assignment in my programming class.

I have 4 radio buttons and 8 checkboxes. radioButton1 = 1, radioButton2 = 2, and so on.

If I select radioButton1 I only want to be able to select only 1 checkBox and have the rest of the checkboxes disabled. How do I go about this?
[pizza place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tPRT.png)
I also want everything to be deselected if i change one of my radiobuttons options after selecting everything else.

I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself well. Hope you can help

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you post your code? That makes it easier to help you.

Comment: I only have pretty much the form in the image Denis Jr :/. i'm kinda blocked. My radioButtons and checkboxes are empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that name (id) of your elements are rb1, rb2... cb1, cb2...

You can make event (click on element > little lighting > double click on checkChanged to generate method) for each of your radio buttons so you can disable checkboxes you want.

Example:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(rb1.Checked == true){ //if someone just checked that radio button
            resetAllButtons(); //resetting all checkbox buttons as you wanted
            cb2.Enabled = false; //making checkbox2 unclickable
            cb3.Enabled = false; //making checkbox3 unclickable
            cb4.Enabled = false; //making checkbox3 unclickable
            /* and so on */
    }
}
```

Method to reset everything should look like:

```
void resetAllButtons(){
    rb1.Checked = false; //unchecking radio button 1
    rb2.Checked = false; //unchecking radio button 2
    /* and so on */
    cb1.Checked = false; //unchecking checkbox1
    cb1.Enabled = true; //making checkbox1 clickable again
    cb2.Checked = false; //unchecking checkbox2
    cb2.Enabled = true; //making checkbox2 clickable again
    /* and so on */
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much someRandomSerbianGuy, would I be able to make a method of the first part too?

Comment: @ReneVazquez I didn't understand your question. Can you please reformulate it? :) Also you can mark my answer as correct so your question remains closed/answered.

Comment: oh, sorry, I meant to ask if there's a way to make the code you have in the first radiobutton to call upon it on the other radiobuttons so I don't have a lot of code

Comment: @ReneVazquez Yes, of course! Instead double clicking on checkChanged you have little arrow (drop down menu) with list of created methods to use instead.